# Mediawiki and how to get list of pages by the template

Tags: templates, mediawiki

Just curious, is there any easy way how go get the list of pages that have specified template inside (e.g. list of all pages on Wikipedia that have Infobox template inside the article)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [WhatLinksHere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere) special page. [Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Template:Infobox)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, John. Appreciate this! Forgot to mention that I'm looking for API for this... And looks like I found it. Here it is: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Infobox

Comment: Funny thing, I have the [documentation page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Embeddedin) for that open right now as I'm working on a [PHP client](https://github.com/johnduhart/Fruity) for the API :-)